# Mostrar datos almacenados de un DateTime a un dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Tengo almacenada una lista de datos los cuales tienen la condición de que su fecha sea de 1 mes anterior a la fecha actual (como se puede ver en el código de abajo) el problema es que quiero mostrar esos datos (los que cumplen la condición anterior mencionada) en un dataGridView.

Cabe mencionar que éste código ya lo he modificado en una pregunta anterior pero fue por otro motivo (Errores en la comprobación del for para conseguir retornar la condición del mes de anterioridad).

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select fecha_mantenimiento from mprev;", con);
    using (MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        dgvmantprev.DataSource = dt;
        string[] desarmar = null;
        string duracion = null;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvmantprev.RowCount; i++)
            {
                duracion = dgvmantprev.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                desarmar = duracion.Split('/');
                DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(desarmar[2]), int.Parse(desarmar[1]), int.Parse(desarmar[0]));
                DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

                if (oldDate.AddMonths(1) < newDate)
                {
                    //Aqui vendría la parte donde agregaría los datos a una lista
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes realizar todo desde la misma consulta `SQL`, Con la funcion `DATEDIFF` podes realizar la condicion y que solo te regrese los datos verdaderos

```
Select fecha_mantenimiento from mprev where fecha_mantenimiento > DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0 + DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()) -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

hola creo que en vez de utilizar split a la celda, utilizar funciones de fecha, tufecha.Day, tufecha.Month, etc... ademas también 
lo puedes traer de la consulta

```
SELECT DAY(fecha_mantenimiento) AS Dia, MONTH(fecha_mantenimiento), Year(fecha_mantenimiento) From mprev  ;
```

y tener tu dt las columnas dia mes año para comprobar por el mes